# Android custom view : draw over toolbar when fragment replaced with animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-custom-view, android-toolbar

I created a custom view which draw a quarter circle :

```
public class QuarterCircle extends View {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.clipRect(mRectClip, Region.Op.REPLACE);
        canvas.rotate(mRotation, mRectClip.right / 2, mRectClip.bottom / 2);
        canvas.drawArc(mRect, 0, 360, false, mPaint);
    }
    ...
}
```

It looks like that :

[image]

When I change fragment with an animation (exit to top), tge view draw over toolbar in a weird way :

[image]

On emulator and some devices, it looks like this. On some other devices, it's cleared after animation stops.

Any clue of what going wrong ?

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: I am seeing the same thing, it only happens for me when I change the clipping region.  Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: You are right, it's the clipping part canvas.clipRect(..) which causes this problem.

Solved by not using clipRect... !